Question About Approximation in Formula For cGMP Synthesis
In this paper, it has a formula.
$\alpha \propto \frac{1}{1 + (\frac{C}{K_{Ca}})^m}$,
Where $\alpha$ is the rate of synthesis of the molecule cGMP, $C$ is the calcium concentration, and $K_{Ca}$ is the calcium concentration at which an enzyme's activity is half of its maximum activity.
The paper later says that since in some conditions, $C >> K_{Ca}$, we can approximate this model as
$\alpha \propto C^{-m}$
I don't understand why we can make this approximation. For example, $10^{-10} >> 10^{-100}$. If $C = 10^{-1}, K_{Ca} = 10^{-100}, m = 2$, then the right-hand side of the first model would be $\frac{1}{1 + 10^{220}} \approx 10^{-220}$. However, the right-hand side of the second model would be $10^{-20}$. Even if you approximate the first model as $\alpha \propto \frac{1}{1 + C^m}$,the right-hand side would be around $10^{-20}$.

All this says is that, if $\frac C{K_{Ca}}$ is large, then we can ignore the $1$ in the denominator.  The constant of proportionality would be $(K_{Ca})^m$.   That's just a constant.

@lulu Okay, thank you!
